# Storing Decimal value in Websql

Tags: sqlite, web-sql

I am trying to store a decimal value like -0.19999999999999998 and 174.18319999453 in a WebSql database.
I however get the value round to -0.2 for -0.19999999999999998 in the database.

I will like to save it as a number, not a string. thank you.

this is my table structure

```
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LOGLOCATION (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name, lat DECIMAL(28, 20), lng DECIMAL(28, 20), desc)");
```

I will be glad if anyone can help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store decimals using `TEXT` data type. Use `value.toString()` function when inserting value into DB and parsing back to decimal using `parseFloat(value)`.

I tried few other approaches but only this one works for me.